# How to run cron job on time and success?

Tags: google-app-engine

I wrote a servlet , accessed from the cron and uploaded to the server. the cron job i wrote was to run the servlet every day 15:25. when i am running it is displaying the message as "55 sec late Hasn't been run" . can you please tell me how to run this cron on Time and be success?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `timezone` correctly? I remember GAE uses UTC as its default timezone (not sure), but you should set it when you want to run your cron job at the right time of your nation.

A simple e.g.:

```
cron:
  description: cron description foo
  url: /your/cron/job/api
  schedule: every day 15:25
  timezone: Asia/Shanghai
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set OK http response to the end of your servlet ?
Like that :

```
//Set Http Response To 200
res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
//Set ContentType
res.setContentType("text/plain");
```